# Words with the suffix -duce

Tags: differences, synonyms

> [deduce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deduce?q=deduce) = 1. arrive at (a fact or a conclusion) by reasoning; draw as a logical conclusion:
>
> [educe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/educe?q=educe) = 1.1. infer (something) from data:
>
> [induce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induce?q=induce) = 4. Logic derive by inductive reasoning:

Would someone please explain how [each prefix + [suffix -duce](http://www.morewords.com/contains/duce/)] induces or implies their modern meanings (assuming  no etymological fallacy)? Since their prefixes differ, I scruple to believe in the equivalence of these particular definitions.

For example, **de = from**. Does this comport with [deduction as a top-down approach](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/dedind.php) ?
Whence does **from** originate?

Moreover, based on this suffix, what general lessons or patterns or shared properties can be deduced about all these words?

Comment: There is also _adduce_, _reduce_, _conduce_, and _transduce_. Using the past participle of the verb (_-duct_ instead of _-duce_), we get a whole separate set of verbs: _abduct_, _adduct_, _deduct_, _conduct_, and _induct_. The Indo-European root that underlies the Latin verb _dūcere_ (_*deuk-_ ‘draw, pull, lead’) is also behind such native English words as _tie_, _tow_, _tug_, _taut_, and even _team_.

Answer (score 1):

### The suffix in question is actual *dūcere*, which Latin for *to lead*

Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deduce) which says

*Deduce* comes from:

> Middle English *deducen*, from Latin *dēdūcere*, to lead away or down :
> *dē-, de- + dūcere,* to lead; see *deuk*- in Indo-European roots.

*Educe* comes from:

> Middle English *educen*, to direct the flow of, from Latin *ēdūcere*: *ē-,
> ex-, ex- + dūcere*, to lead; see *deuk*- in Indo-European roots.

and *induce* comes from:

> Middle English *inducen*, from Old French *inducer*, from Latin *indūcere*:
> *in-, in*; see **in**-2 + *dūcere*, to lead; see *deuk*- in Indo-European roots.